# Scala parameters pattern (Spray routing example)

Tags: scala, spray, shapeless

Sorry about the vague title...wasn't sure how to characterize this.

I've seen/used a certain code construction in Scala for some time but I don't know how it works.  It looks like this (example from Spray routing):

```
path( "foo" / Segment / Segment ) { (a,b) => {  // <-- What's this style with a,b?
...
}}
```

In this example, the Segements in the path are bound to a and b respectively inside the associated block.  I know how to use this pattern but how does it work?  Why didn't it bind something to "foo"?

I'm not so interested in how spray works for my purpose here, but what facility of Scala is this, and how would I write my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Senia's answer is helpful in understanding the Spray-routing directives and how they use HLists to do their work.  But I get the impression you were really just interested in the Scala constructs used in

```
path( "foo" / Segment / Segment ) { (a,b) => ... }
```

It sounds as though you are interpreting this as special Scala syntax that in some way connects those two `Segment` instances to `a` and `b`.  That is not the case at all.

```
path( "foo" / Segment / Segment )
```

is just an ordinary call to `path` with a single argument, an expression involving two calls to a `/` method.  Nothing fancy, just an ordinary method invocation.

The result of that call is a function which wants another function -- the thing you want to happen when a matching request comes in -- as an argument.  That's what this part is:

```
{ (a,b) => ... }
```

It's just a function with two arguments.  The first part (the invocation of `path`) and the second part (what you want done when a matching message is received) are not *syntactically* connected in any way.  They are completely separate to Scala.  However, *Spray's semantics* connects them: the first part creates a function that will call the second part when a matching message is received.

Comment: I should confess that this is a somewhat simplified explanation with regard to what Spray is actually doing, but being more accurate would have made things less clear.  I figured that since the focus was on whether this was Scala syntax I would go for clarity.

Comment: Simplified answer. Worked with clarity, for me.Thanks @AmigoNico

Answer (score 11):

This code is from a class that extends `Directives`. So all methods of `Directives` are in scope.

### PathMatcher

There is no method `/` in `String`, so [an implicit conversion](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L122) is used to convert `String` to `PathMatcher0` ([`PathMatcher[HNil]`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/package.scala#L27)) with [method `/`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L33).

Method `/` takes a `PathMatcher` and returns a `PathMatcher`.

[`Segment`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L336) is a `PathMatcher1[String]` (`PathMatcher[String :: HNil]`).

Method `/` of `PathMatcher[HNil]` with `PathMatcher[String :: HNil]` parameter returns a `PathMatcher[String :: HNil]`.

Method `/` of `PathMatcher[String :: HNil]` with `PathMatcher[String :: HNil]` parameter returns a `PathMatcher[String :: String :: HNil]`. It's black magic from [`shapeless`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). See heterogenous lists [concatenation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L71); it is worth reading.

### Directive

So you are calling [method `path`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/PathDirectives.scala#L31) with `PathMatcher[String :: String :: HNil]` as a parameter. It returns a `Directive[String :: String :: HNil]`.

Then you are calling method `apply` on `Directive` with `Function2[?, ?, ?]` (`(a, b) => ..`) as a parameter. There is an appropriate implicit conversion (see black magic) for every `Directive[A :: B :: C ...]` that creates an object with method `apply((a: A, b: B, c: C ...) => Route)`.

### Parsing

`PathMatcher` contains rules for path parsing. It returns its result as an `HList`.

The "foo" matcher [matches](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L123) a String and ignores it (returns `HNil`).

The `A / B` matcher combines 2 matchers (`A` and `B`) separated by a "/" string. It concatenates the results of `A` and `B` using `HList` concatenation.

The `Segment` matcher [matches](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L338) a path segment and returns it as a `String :: HNil`.

So `"foo" / Segment / Segment` matches a path of 3 segments, ignores the first one and returns the remaining segments as `String :: String :: HNil`.

Then black magic allows you to use `Function2[String, String, Route]` (`(String, String) => Route`) to process `String :: String :: HNil`. Without such magic you would have to use the method like this: `{case a :: b :: HNil => ...}`.

### Black magic

As @AlexIv noted:

There is an implicit conversion [`pimpApply`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L124) for every `Directive[A :: B :: C ...]` that creates an object with method `apply((a: A, b: B, c: C ...) => Route)`.

It accepts `ApplyConverter` implicitly. Type member [`In`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/ApplyConverter.scala#L22) of `ApplyConverter` represents an appropriate function `(A, B, C ...) => Route` for every `Directive[A :: B :: C ...]`.

There is no way to create such implicit values without macros or boilerplate code. So [`sbt-boilerplate`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate) is used for `ApplyConverter` generation. See [`ApplyConverterInstances.scala`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/boilerplate/spray/routing/ApplyConverterInstances.scala.template).

Comment: As for apply in Directive, there is an implicit conversion to Directive `happly` [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L124)

Comment: Actually for this they are using typeclass/magnet pattern ApplyConverter which is generated with [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate), there is a file `ApplyConverterInstances.scala` which is generted for all other cases

Answer (score 1):

Some additional note to **senia** answer, which is really good.

When you write something like this:

```
path("foo" / Segment / Segment) { (a,b) => {...} }
```

you are calling apply method on [Directive](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L58) like **senia** wrote, but there is no `apply` method in Directive, so spray is using implicit [conversion](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L124) to [happly](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L59) method. As you can `pimpApply` is implemented with typeclass pattern [ApplyConverter](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/ApplyConverter.scala#L21), which is defined only for `Directive0` by default. As you can see it's companion object extends `ApplyConverterInstances`, which is generated with [sbt-bolierplate](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate) plugin

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you look into source?
2. As for me, it could be implemented as follows

   - method `path` takes arbitrary type parameter, some pattern-object of that type and a function from that type:

     ```
     def path[T](pattern:Pattern[T])(function:Function[T, `some other type like unit or any`])
     ```
   - the pattern is constructed with two tricks.

     - The String is either "pimped" to have method `/` or has an implicit convertion to `Pattern[Nothing]`
     - the `Pattern[T]` has method `/` that constructs another pattern with some new type. The method takes single argument (some ancestor of Segment). I guess — Pattern[T2]:

       ```
       trait Pattern[T] {
           ///
           def `/`[T2](otherPattern:Pattern[T2]):Pattern[(T,T2)] 
       }
       ```
3. So the first argument of `path` allows to determine the constructed type of pattern as being the pair. Thus we get proper type for the second argument.
4. The actual matching work is done inside `path`. I thought it was out of the questions scope.

Comment: [Method `path`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/PathDirectives.scala#L31) returns `Directive` (in this case `Directive[String :: String :: HNil]`) and there is no method `apply(String, String)` in `Directive`. It's not so simple.

Comment: Looking only at the given code I couldn't guess about some "black magic" behind the scene. Of course there are many implementations possible. The given answer is a simple possible implementation.

Comment: `(a,b) => {...}` is `Function2`, not `Function1`. So tricky part is how to use `Function1` with `path( "foo" / Segment )`, `Function2` with `path( "foo" / Segment / Segment )` and so on. You could create 22 boilerplate methods, but it's not scala way. And the other problem: `(a / b) / c` and `a / (b / c)` should return the same result, so it's even more boilerplate code. And `/` is not the only combination method - there are other `PathMatcher` combinators.

Comment: My point is: you can't create such generic API this way. You'll have to use `PartialFunction`s as in scala parser combinators.

Comment: Yes. I've got your point. It cannot be generally constructed with tuples.
Once I implemented something of the kind and I had similar problem of being unable to convert nested tuples `(a, (b, c))` to an appropriate `Function` type. Thus I had to use an imperfect set of boilerplate methods. I see that scalaz' HList solves the problem.

Comment: "scalaz' HList"? Do you mean [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) `HList`?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's shapeless' HList. **scalaz** and **shapeless** are listed in http://typelevel.org/projects/ and I've messed them.