# Is there a boilerplate-free way to convert HLists to an argument list?

Tags: scala, macros, spray, shapeless, hlist

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18395023/3566695) Spray uses sbt-boilerplate to generate `ApplyConverter` instances that implicitly convert `A :: B :: ... :: HNil => R` to the more traditional `(A, B, ...) => R` for ease of use. That question was asked over a year ago; can this now be done using, for example, macros or Shapeless's newer functionality so that an external code generation step isn't required?

Comment: IMO the boilerplate should be part of shapeless. I [once asked a similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/shapeless-dev/cNQWSE4uAzs/discussion) on the mailing but didn't follow up. So, if you need that functionality it may make sense to ask again.

Comment: I'm confused ... this has been part of shapeless almost since the beginning ... what am I missing?

Comment: @MilesSabin First let me just say thanks for shapeless and all the work you've put into it, I think it's an awesome library for Scala! But I wanted to know if it were possible without "external code generation" by which I imprecisely meant as in a way that does some type-level magic so that you could somehow recursively inject the arguments into the function or something, or put another way a method that doesn't rely on a separate instance for each `FunctionN`. As far as I can tell, shapeless is still generating its FnFromProduct instances using a template.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "external code generation". As a user of shapeless you wouldn't have to resort to any form of code generation. Code generation is used internally to shapeless, certainly, mirroring the code generation in the Scala standard library and compiler ... given the way that Scala function types are currently defined (ie. as completely unrelated) this is unavoidable. The sensible way out of this would be for a hypothetical Scala variant to take curried function types as primary ... however desirable that might be I don't see it happening any time soon.

Comment: So I guess I'm asking two distinct questions: one, is this possible with shapeless and the answer is yes, but two, is this possible in vanilla Scala without code duplication and the answer is no. I think Miles' answer more directly answers my question so I'll tick that as the answer however I also don't think lmm's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been included in shapeless for a very long time. In shapeless 2.0.0 you can do the following,

```
scala> import shapeless._, syntax.std.function._
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.function._

scala> val f1: (Int, String, Boolean) => Int = (i, s, b) => i+s.length+(if(b) 1 else 0)
f1: (Int, String, Boolean) => Int = <function3>

scala> val pf1 = f1.toProduct
pf1: Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil => Int = <function1>

scala> pf1(23 :: "foo" :: true :: HNil)
res0: Int = 27

scala> val pf2: (Int :: String :: HNil) => Int = l => l.head+l.tail.head.length
pf2: Int :: String :: HNil => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2 = pf2.fromProduct
f2: (Int, String) => Int = <function2>

scala> f2(23, "foo")
res1: Int = 26
```

(REPL result type rendering tidied for readability).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this in pure Scala, as there is no way to generically talk about the `FunctionN` interfaces. At the macro level it would be possible, but not in a way that makes use of the AST representation available; a macro to do this would probably be reduced to (effectively) doing string manipulation - in which case there's very little advantage over sbt-boilerplate.

Even if it did become possible, Spray is a fairly foundational library that needs to be usable in conjunction with other libraries (thus it continues to build releases against old versions of Scala and Akka) - something that will only become more important if and when Play is ported to run on top of Spray. So I would expect it will be a while before Spray introduces a hard dependency on Shapeless 2 (which is incompatible with Shapeless 1), and until then I imagine they'll try and keep the code for the shapeless2 build of spray-routing as close as possible to that for the shapeless1 build for ease of maintenance.

Comment: FYI: actually, spray probably won't get any big updates like this any more. Instead, new development efforts will mostly get to akka-http. In the routing part of akka-http the dependency on shapeless2 was completely removed and the DSL is now based on Scala tuples instead of on HLists. That said, the problem remains exactly the same and boilerplate needs to generated like before.

Comment: Btw. Why wouldn't that work: "At the macro level it would be possible, but not in a way that makes use of the AST representation available". At the macro level you have access to all the types so you can do any type-y calculations you want to.

Comment: That's awful, I hope they reconsider. HLists are much better than Scala tuples, and I have production Spray code that depends on this difference. As for your question, the macro level has access to the types but there's nothing that knows about the relationship between the different `FunctionN` interfaces. So the macro would have to use string manipulation to get the correct `FunctionN`. It's not that the macro can't do it, it's that the macro can't do it any better than a text processor.

Comment: I don't think you have to operate with `FunctionN` interfaces in a macro. There's an AST element for an anonymous function where you just have to pass in the right number of parameters. That said, I think I understand what you are saying: at some level you need to do a kind of stupid translation (and it would rather better be done directly in the compiler).

Comment: Regarding the change to tuples: I don't think it is as bad as you think. What we've done (I did the change, in fact) was to remove the hard dependency on shapeless which on its own is a good thing in the first place (one dependency less you can get conflicts with). This doesn't mean that HLists won't be supported any more. The idea is that there will be an optional connector module which provides enough helpers to reenable patterns that were previously possible with the direct HList support. This works because for shapeless it doesn't  matter if you work with HLists or tuples or case classes.

Comment: I just created a ticket to akka, that we don't forget about that extra module: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16343. I invite you to add a comment about how you use spray in combination with shapeless which won't work as is with the new tuple-based approach. That would be very helpful! Thanks for the discussion here anyways :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've somehow managed to forget what led me to ask this question in the first place but I sat down and tried to implement a function to convert an HList to an argument list anyway and ran head-first into the exact thing @lmm describes: HLists let you abstract over the arity of values but there's no way in Scala to abstract over the arity of a function. Oh well. At least now I've got a better understand of the limits of Scala :)